# Enter a value into a nested hash from a sequence of keys

Tags: perl

I have a set of keys stored in an array that I would like to splice into a nested hash. For example I might have:

```
$hash->{$key1} = $value;
```

And what I would like to do is add in additional dimensions to the hash, eg:

```
my @array = ( $key2, $key3 ) ;
```

to give

```
$hash->{$key1}->{$key2}->{$key3} = $value;
```

I do not know beforehand how many keys will be in the array.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: It's written there. How do you insert the keys?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my @keys = qw/ a b c /;
my $val = 99;

my $hash = { };

{
    my $h = $hash;

    $h = $h->{ shift @keys } = {} while @keys > 1;

    $h->{ shift @keys } = $val;
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper $hash;
```

#### output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'a' => {
                   'b' => {
                            'c' => 99
                          }
                 }
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use Data::Diver qw( DiveVal );

DiveVal($hash, map \$_, $key1, @array) = $value;
  -or-
DiveVal($hash->{$key1}, map \$_, @array) = $value;
```

or

```
sub dive_val :lvalue { my $p = \shift; $p = \( $$p->{$_} ) for @_; $$p }

dive_val($hash, $key1, @array) = $value;
  -or-
dive_val($hash->{$key1}, @array) = $value;
```